# Steps to make a mobile application using drupal as a back end or service

Tags: android, drupal

I want to make a mobile application with drupal as back end because already done the same application as a website.I want to use the same drupal for my android application

Please any one help me with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phone: [phonegap drupal](http://drupal.org/project/phonegap)

Drupal: [services](http://drupal.org/project/services)

Drupal: [libraries api](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/libraries) Not to be confused with the other library that's for 6.

Secure Login drupal: [oAuth](http://drupal.org/project/oauth)

Secure login android: [Oauth/ID](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps)

Tutorial: [a monster tutorial](http://www.tylerfrankenstein.com/code/android-app-with-drupal-7-services-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile)

Tutorial: [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-drupal-web-service-project/index.html#resources) Create a custom web services Grate write up must read.

Videos: [services videos](http://tutr.tv/search/apachesolr_search/services)

Important fix for Services ATM: [fixes for SPYC](http://drupal.org/node/1313976)

This will give you a basic JSON API, If you follow that tutorial you should be aware your passwords are plain text over whatever airport wifi your clients happen to be passing through. Oauth will fix that. The tutorial dosn't give chrome extensions

Chrome: [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) - best debugger for rest I've seen on chrome.

Android specific HTTP videos: [3 episodes 200 episode list](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxcfhAU2dDg&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5&index=147&feature=plpp_video)

source code to that HTTP stuff and much more [mybringback](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/828/thenewboston-sample-projects/)

Hint: The stuff about twitter's json & sutch is EXACTLY what your getting from drupal, this is why it's included for native development.

Iphone&Drupal: [iphone & json video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syqsH2CEu6U&feature=share&list=PLDD68083E136B3AE9) Not what your after per say but lets you watch someone write a quick module to patch services into there phone. I I recommend skipping to 5:35 after the install takes place.

Android: [http-wraper & examples](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/JSON)

Android: [another HTTP wrap](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/06/12/a-basic-http-client-for-android-and-more/)

Android: [another another http wrap](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client)

Drupal: [views datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) Enable views to spit out the JSON would work for much simpler projects where you don't care about user authentication, just using Drupal's CMS magic to glue the pieces together.

Answer (score 1):

Try to build a simple app using a webview http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

in this view you can just display your drupal CMS using your existing url

Comment: I dont want as webview. I want to make it as a native android application with drupal as a webservice

Comment: Maybe you could use a REST interface or sth to query everything from the website as a backend, but honestly I wouldn't recommend that because of performance issues...

Comment: Any tutorial you know for this

Comment: for rest & android? -> http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/

Answer (score 0):

In our company we use drupal with REST api. We've created our own custom module which creates JSON files based on the nodes from drupal. From the app we then get these JSON files if there is new content.

Comment: I want to make this because i have less exp in drupal

Comment: @Krishna but it is a drupal module we use. You need experience with drupal if you want to make this kind of thing since you are going to use the drupal database etc.

Comment: @Krishna We are starting to consider making our own since drupal is starting to show its limitations, drupal is build for websites not giving content to mobile apps.